# how can sql return column data that is not in the table?

Tags: mysql, debugging, sequelize.js

This is my table:

[image]

As you can see below, there is a query returning UserId, that is not in my table:

[image]

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO "Patrons" ("id","name","jumlah","donaturId","category","createdAt","updatedAt")
    VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)
    RETURNING "id","name","jumlah","donaturId","category","createdAt","updatedAt","UserId";
```

I just try to basic query to create data with sequelize..

Comment: Please don't use links, include all possible information as text..

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75426309/edit) replacing the table image with a markdown table (and/or `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT`s), and the code should be text between [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). Your `RETURNING` clause is a PostgreSQL and MariaDB >= 10.5.0 _"thing"_, not MySQL.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)